# Splitting a git repo at a commit hash and merge it later

Tags: git, gitlab

(rewrote the question with more context)
We are moving from Perforce to Git (likely GitLab). We have 1 repo. We don't want to carry our 25+ years of history to GitLab as it is pretty huge even after trimming off binaries. But developers would like to be able to seamlessly look at the history of a file across several commits and this would be lost if they only had access to the latest revision.

I am using git-p4 to migrate to a local git repo first.

1. I can get the head revision only using *git p4 --use-client-spec //depot .*
   If I push this to GitLab I get the single commit based on the head revision in Perforce.
2. Or I can migrate along with certain amount of history in perforce as individual commits into git using _git p4 --use-client-spec //depot@4,6
   If I push this into GitLab I get 3 commits.

Assuming commits (hashes) like for the full history of the repo:

6666
5555
4444
3333
2222
1111

If I followed #2 above, I would have commits 4444,5555,6666 in my local git repo and I can push these to GitLab as my active_source repo.

I could then create a new local repo with 1111,2222,3333 and push to GitLab as my archive_source repo.

All developers will check out the active_source repo and work on that. But some would need also the history in archive_source repo.

Can they somehow pull active_source repo on top of archive_source so that they can see the history all the way from 6666 to 1111 ?

All examples I found were about splitting the repo "along the length", but not at a certain commit and be able to stitch it back together for history.

Thank you,

-Sachin

Comment: History, in a Git repository, is the set of commits in the repository. The commits *are* the history. Either you have commits that are history, or you don't have commits and don't have history. There's no such thing as "file history". Just make commits or don't.

Comment: `push the repo starting at 4444 to GitLab` I do not understand, there is no "repo starting at 4444". What you can do, is that you can _squeeze_ 1111 2222 3333 4444 into a single big commit and push it, if you want. That _will_ be a separate commit with separate history, and should be faster.

Answer (score 0):

I found an excellent blog post and the actual source in the git book to solve this issue. Instead of merely posting links to those I am now expanding the answer.

We basically split the history at a specific hash. Both historical and current will have the common hash (3333 in this example). Then we squash the current upto the parent of the common hash and discard the parents in the current.

This is done by a rebase and the parent of the common hash is a newly generated free-floating commit that we attach the current to. Historical and current can then be 2 different repos saved independently.

To put these together and view the total history, if needed, we knock off the new parent of the common hash and use git-replace to attach to the historical.

## Steps

1. We branch the repo at the hash 3333

> ```
> git branch archive_source 3333
> ```

2. Push it to remote

> ```
> git init /users/myusername/historical_src
> git add remote history /users/myusername/historical_src
> git push history archive_source:main
> ```

3. Now we squash the history of the "current" branch

> ```
> > git commit-tree -m "For historic commits, run 'git replace <child-ID> > 3333'" "3333~^{tree}"  
> 12345abcdf67890ghijk  << returned commit hash
> ```

4. Now we rebase the current source onto this squashed commit hash. This will rewrite the hashes of the current repo (rewrite its history)

> ```
> > git rebase 3333~ --onto 12345abcd  --rebase-merges
> ```

Done! You can check that the history is truncated by running git log

Now to reassemble at the developers machine:

1. Fetch the archive data

> ```
> > git remote add historical /users/myusername/historical_src 
> > git fetch historical
> ```

2. Setup a branch:

> ```
> > git branch history historical:main
> ```

3. Connect the current and history together by replacing the common commit between the two.

> ```
> > git replace 9876a 3333
> ```

The cleanup etc

> ```
> > git replace -d 9876a 
> > git branch -d history
> > git remote remove historical
> ```

I found the answer and a clear explanation in a recent article that I came across:

https://andrewlock.net/reducing-the-size-of-a-git-repository-with-git-replace/

This is based on: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Replace