# How to move new commits from git-p4 to a different repo

Tags: git, gitlab, git-rebase, git-p4

I am using `git p4 clone //depot/...@all .`  to initially get source from perforce to a local git repo. I push it to remote.
I then periodically use `git p4 rebase //depot/... .` to get the latest code to the local git repo. Push it to remote.

Because of the size of our history I am truncating the history and creating a "current_src" repo on remote which has limited history. I use rebase for this so the commit hashes no longer match with what I pushed from my local repo.

Now when I push newly retrieved source from git-p4 to this remote "current_src" I get a ton of conflicts.

Is there a way I can automate the push of only new source from git-p4 to the remote current_src which has different commit hashes due to the rebase?

Just for the sake of context this is how I truncate history: [Splitting a git repo at a commit hash and merge it later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71685527/splitting-a-git-repo-at-a-commit-hash-and-merge-it-later)

Comment: A truncated history (properly grounded like yours) *is* a **new repository**. You should simply abandon the old repository and create a new (empty) one on GitLab. Push the commits to the new empty repository, and now you have a new repository containing only the new history of commits.

Comment: @torek I tried the option of pushing my truncated history to a new repo. But as I mentioned I need to keep topping it off with new code from perforce (which I get using git-p4 rebase). How do I push the new commits I get from perforce to the new repo and avoid (several) conflicts? Thanks.

Comment: Ah - new repositories are incompatible with old ones; it's very difficult (though not impossible) to copy such commits into the new repository. You'll need to write your own program to do this.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [Git p4](https://git-scm.com/book/id/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-as-a-Client#_getting_started_4), you could, for each new Perforce revision, create a git-p4 shallow clone which creates a new Git repository with only the very latest Perforce revision imported into it.

That would be a way to "split your Git repository history": leave your old repository intact, and start a new one.

Try and use that new Git repository for the next few `git p4 rebase //depot/...` and see if you have conflicts then.

Comment: Hi @VonC, As I explained in my link I wanted the ability to keep the history for developers to look older commits as well. So it is not just a matter of splitting git history, but to split with the idea to be able to stitch them back together (as explained in the link).. Which is why I believe I cannot create a brand new repo from a certain point in Perforce history..

Comment: @SachinMyneni Understood. I hope you will find a solution.